# Manipulate parameter in php

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I'm relatively inexperienced with PHP and I'm trying to make some changes to an existing code base.  I have a method that takes an array as a parameter:

```
public function get_ids(array $order)
{
    ...
    return $ret_val;
}
```

I want to add an additional element to this array, paired with the key `count`.  I know that key doesn't exist.  My understanding from the PHP documentation is that all variables are pass-by-reference:

> Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument
>   by reference. As of PHP 5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that
>   "call-time pass-by-reference" is deprecated when you use & in
>   foo(&$a);. And as of PHP 5.4.0, call-time pass-by-reference was
>   removed, so using it will raise a fatal error.

However, when I do:

```
public function get_ids(array $order)
{
    ...
    $order['count'] = 5;
    return $ret_val;
}
```

and then do a `var_dump` in the method that called this method, there's no key for "count".  However, if I do a `var_dump`right before the `get_ids` method returns, there clearly *is* a key for `count`.

What's up? I'm clearly not understanding a principal of PHP but my usual Googling skills are completely failing me.

Comment: That quote is when you *call* the function, not when you are *defining* the function. You should still define the function as accepting its parameters by reference if that is the intended behavior.

Comment: @nickb OHHHHHH. Yep. Totally understand the context now. I thought they meant "simply defining the function means it will be passed by reference."  Clearly not. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like said in the description of the deprecated feature :

`Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass the argument by reference`

So specify that you want you parameter pass by reference in you function definition.

```
public function get_ids(array &$order)
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My from the PHP documentation is that all variables are
>   pass-by-reference:

All parameters are passed by value if not prepended with `&`, and are passed by reference if prepended with `&`.